# Capture Function in PowerShell Closure

Tags: function, powershell, closures

It appears that PowerShell closures do not capture the definition of functions:

```
PS C:\> function x() { Write-Host 'original x' }
PS C:\> function x-caller-generator() { return { Write-host 'Calling x!'; x }.GetNewClosure() }
PS C:\> $y = x-caller-generator
PS C:\> & $y
Calling x!
original x
PS C:\> function x() { Write-Host 'new x' }
PS C:\> & $y
Calling x!
new x
```

Is there any way to capture the definition of a function?

What I'm actually experiencing is that I create a closure, but when my closure is executed, the function is out of scope somehow. (It's some strangeness the [psake](https://github.com/psake/psake) module for build scripting is doing.) Something like this:

```
PS C:\> function closure-maker () {
>>     function x() { Write-Host 'x!' }
>>
>>     return { Write-host 'Calling x'; x }.GetNewClosure()
>> }
>>
PS C:\> $y = closure-maker
PS C:\> & $y
Calling x
The term 'x' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:39
+     return { Write-host 'Calling x'; x <<<<  }.GetNewClosure()
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (x:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Note: Using PowerShell 2.0, but interested in 3.0 answers if there's something new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I found something that works for simple functions at least. We can use `Get-Item` to get an object describing the function and then pull the original script off that. Like this:

```
function x-caller-generator() {
    $xFunc = [ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Item function:x).Definition)
    return { Write-host 'Calling x!'; & $xFunc }.GetNewClosure()
}
```

If the function is never redefined (like in my example where my function is out of scope), we can avoid pulling off the definition and just use the function object directly:

```
function closure-maker () {
    function x() { Write-Host 'x!' }

    $xFunc = Get-Item function:x
    return { Write-host 'Calling x'; & $xFunc }.GetNewClosure()
}
```

This second method will **not** work if the function is redefined (at least in the same scope as the original function) before the closure is executed. The object is apparently dynamic; it tracks the current definition.

I seriously doubt this would work with a function that references other user defined functions that could also be out of scope, but my use case didn't require that.

Sample output:

Creating script block

```
PS C:\> function x() { Write-Host 'original x' }
PS C:\> function x-caller-generator() { $xFunc = [ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Item function:x).Definition); return { Write-host 'Calling x!'; & $xFunc }.GetNewClosure() }
PS C:\> $y = x-caller-generator
PS C:\> & $y
Calling x!
original x
PS C:\> function x() { Write-Host 'new x' }
PS C:\> & $y
Calling x!
original x
```

Using function object

```
PS C:\> function closure-maker () {
>>     function x() { Write-Host 'x!' }
>>
>>     $xFunc = Get-Item function:x
>>     return { Write-host 'Calling x'; & $xFunc }.GetNewClosure()
>> }
>>
PS C:\> $y = closure-maker
PS C:\> & $y
Calling x
x!
```

Trying to use object with first example **does not work**:

```
PS C:\> function x() { Write-Host 'original x' }
PS C:\> function x-caller-generator() { $xFunc = Get-Item function:x; return { Write-host 'Calling x!'; & $xFunc }.GetNewClosure() }
PS C:\> $y = x-caller-generator
PS C:\> & $y
Calling x!
original x
PS C:\> function x() { Write-Host 'new x' }
PS C:\> & $y
Calling x!
new x
```

Answer (score 0):

A small correction will let the first example work:

```
clear
function x() { Write-Host 'original x' }
function x-caller-generator() { 
      $xFunc = $function:x; # instead of Get-Item
      return { Write-host 'Calling x!'; & $xFunc }.GetNewClosure() 
}
$y = x-caller-generator
& $y
function x() { Write-Host 'new x' }
& $y
```

Output:

```
Calling x!
original x
Calling x!
original x
```

PowerShell has too many looks alike which actually behave differently. You can get a function object by using $function prefix. One might think it works the same way as the Get-Item, but it does not...